# Throwable getCause returns null

Tags: java, throwable

I am catching a `Throwable` error.

```
catch (Throwable t){    
    System.out.println(t.getCause().getMessage());
}
```

When I put a breakpoint on a line `System.out.`, and hover over (Eclipse) the `t` variable, Eclipse shows me the cause: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myclass`

But when I release the breakpoint I am getting `null` for `t.getCause()`.

Why does it happen? How can I get the cause string.

**UPDATE:**

Same happens if I catch

```
catch (NoClassDefFoundError e){
}
```

Comment: 1. you should NOT catch `Throwable`; 2. `.getCause()` tries and sees what the _parent_ `Throwable` is, if any.

Comment: Why do you *expect* the cause to be non-null here? Not every exception is caused by another one...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, but why eclspse debugger sees the cause?

Comment: @yuris: The `t` variable *is* the `NoClassDefFoundError`. Just call `System.out.println(t)` or `System.out.println(t.getMessage())`. If you expand `t` in Eclipse, you'll find that that exception doesn't have a cause... I think you've misunderstood what `getCause()` is there for.

Comment: @yuris probably because Eclipse wraps the exception into one of its own; but on actual runs you won't have Eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the [docs - `Throwable#getCause`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29):

> Returns the cause of this throwable or **`null`** if the cause is
>   nonexistent or unknown. (The cause is the throwable that caused this
>   throwable to get thrown.)

So when you do:

```
t.getCause().getMessage()
```

It's like writing:

```
null.getMessage()
```

Which of course causes [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

You can simply do:

```
catch (NoClassDefFoundError e){
   System.out.println(e.getMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause value is the cause of this throwable exception. To make getCause() return a value you can check an example of my peace of code.

```
class Dog {

    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Bark Bark");
        throw new NullPointerException("message");
    }
}
```

> 

```
    try {
            // create an object of Dog
            Dog dog = new Dog();

            // create an object of Class
            // using getClass()
            Class obj = dog.getClass();

            // using object of Class to
            // get all the declared methods of Dog
            Method[] methods = obj.getDeclaredMethods();

            // create an object of the Method class
            for (Method m : methods) {
                Object[] parameters = new Object[] {};
                m.invoke(dog, parameters);
            }
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            System.out.println(e); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

FYI:
`e.getTargetException()` is the same as `e.getCause()`

InvocationTargetException is a checked exception that wraps an exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor.

[InvocationTargetException DOC link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html#:%7E:text=InvocationTargetException%20is%20a%20checked%20exception,general%20purpose%20exception%2Dchaining%20mechanism)

Some related info [Chained Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html)